Horror movie about two cannibal old ladies
It's an American horror movie released between 2000 and 2015.  
It begins with a man skiing or riding a snow mobile.  Something happens, either he gets hurt or runs out of gas, so he has to go on foot.  He passes an old building and either finally finds a small house or faints.  He comes unconscious at some point.
He ends up waking up tied to a chair by these two old ladies, who are cannibals and plan on eating him like they did to so many men before him.
He is maybe in his 50 to 60's and the old women look like witches and have jars with pickled body parts of men.  He tries all through the movie to convince them not to eat him, even saying he is attracted to them, but they don't believe him and tell him to prove it.  He tries by getting a hard on. 
He escapes in the ending (I think).

Sounds like the thriller Suspended Animation from 2001.

Animator Thomas Kempton gets more than he bargained for when a snowmobile trip turns to terror in the wilds of Northern Michigan. Held prisoner by two cannibalistic sisters who try unsuccessfully to add him to their long list of victims, Tom becomes obsessed with tracking down his captor's long lost daughter. The ensuing drama becomes perfect material for Tom's latest Hollywood screenplay, inevitably luring one cannibal sister back to her original prey.

You can see them tying him to a wheelchair in the trailer:



